# Header size changes after adding bootstrap.min.cs

Tags: html, css

When I  link `bootstrap.min.css` to my webpage, header size of the webpage increases.

I don't need to change header size. Please help me to add `bootstrap.min.css` without increasing header size.

I'm new to bootstrap. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you add boostrap then you have option from this to elements.
Add your CSS under the boostrap, and change the proporties for header size.

Should work :)

Comment: thanks for the reply . But it doesn't solve the problem. :(

Comment: What style option you have for header in your css?

Comment: I'm using a class name `form-basic`.

Comment: `.form-basic h1{display :inline-block; box-sizing : border-box;} `

Comment: You dont add any option for size like even hight or width.
Here's link to some info:  w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp).

Comment: No I didn't add a static height before. But now I tried it and it doesn't work either.

Comment: You need to add your own hight/width (on px, % or other to DIV container, not to h1 block.

It must work...

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I'll try it

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to bootstrap
Yeah its good you're learning.

The thing with *bootstrap.min.css* is it has its own styles written for html elements. As bootstrap has it's own classes you can add a style for the  element or can use  or any other if you want to shrink the font size in the view.

Best practice - Customize the style using css.